# Using FromRawSql in EF Core 5.0 throws an exception

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I have an entity (DTO) in EF Core 5.0 with PK of type Guid with Pomelo connector for MySql DB. The PK is mapped as binary(16) in MySql.

Eg:

```
this.DbContext.Set<TEntity>().FromSqlRaw(@"select * from <TableName> Id = {0};)", Id).ToList()
```

Error:

> MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= _binary'ٗ?^?K??Vݧ??';)

Would like to know if this is due to incomaptible type match Guid <-> binary(16)?

This throws Sql parse exception (full-stack):

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query: Error: An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'DocuSign.Adm.Agreements.Data.AgreementDbContext'.
MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= _binary'ٗ?^?K??Vݧ??';)
) AS `a`
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `a0`.`PartyId`,' at line 3
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ResultSet.cs:line 50
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 135
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.CreateAsync(CommandListPosition commandListPosition, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, IDictionary`2 cachedProcedures, IMySqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 444
   at MySqlConnector.Core.CommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 commands, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/CommandExecutor.cs:line 60
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 314
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 256
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()

MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= _binary'ٗ?^?K??Vݧ??';)
) AS `a`
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `a0`.`PartyId`,' at line 3
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ResultSet.cs:line 50
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 135
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.CreateAsync(CommandListPosition commandListPosition, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, IDictionary`2 cachedProcedures, IMySqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 444
   at MySqlConnector.Core.CommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 commands, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/CommandExecutor.cs:line 60
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 314
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 256
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
'this.DbContext.Set<TEntity>().FromSqlRaw(@"select * from agreements ParentId = {0};)", parentId).ToList()' threw an exception of type 'MySqlConnector.MySqlException'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    ErrorCode (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException): -2147467259
    ErrorCode: ParseError
    HResult: -2147467259
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    IsTransient: false
    Message: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= _binary'\bٗ?^?K\u000f??Vݧ?\u0006?';)\r\n) AS `a`\r\nLEFT JOIN (\r\n    SELECT `a0`.`PartyId`,' at line 3"
    Number: 1064
    Source: "System.Private.CoreLib"
    SqlState: "42000"
    StackTrace: "   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.<ReadResultSetHeaderAsync>d__2.MoveNext() in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ResultSet.cs:line 50\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 137\r\n   at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.<CreateAsync>d__97.MoveNext() in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 445\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at MySqlConnector.Core.CommandExecutor.<ExecuteReaderAsync>d__0.MoveNext() in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/CommandExec
utor.cs:line 60\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.<ExecuteReaderAsync>d__75.MoveNext() in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 314\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 256\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()\r\n   at Mic
rosoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)\r\n   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)"
    TargetSite: {Void Throw()}
    m_data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
```

Comment: Please share the actual failing SQL statement

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you forgot WHERE keyword.
This should work

```
this.DbContext.Set<TEntity>().FromSqlRaw(@"select * from <TableName> where Id = {0};)", Id).ToList()
```

Comment: **@Rafabd** In addition to that, you might want to consider using [FromSqlInterpolated()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsqlinterpolated?view=efcore-5.0) instead of `FromSqlRaw()`, if you are crafting dynamic SQL statements without using command parameters. See [Raw SQL Queries: Passing parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#passing-parameters) for further information.